# Will a shell script written on ubuntu kernel always be able to run on RHEL also

Tags: unix

I want to know that if a shell script is created and tested on ubuntu kernel, then will it always without fail also run on RHEL kernel provided the correct shell is invoked for running the script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ways in which the execution may differ when used on different distributions and different kernels:

- Differences in the version and configuration of the Linux kernel - this may affect presence and format of the contents of files such as those in `/proc` and `/sys`, or the presence of particular device drivers.
- Differences in the version of the shell used - `/bin/sh` may be Bash on one system and Dash on another, or Bash 3.x on one system and Bash 4.x on the other.
- Differences in the installed programs your script invokes (and, if you got your package dependencies wrong, whether those programs are even present - what's "essential" on one distribution may be "optional" on another).

In short, different distributions have the same issues as different versions of one distribution, but more so.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what shell/interpreter it was written for and versions of the particular shell it was written for. For example, a bash script written using bash-4.4 may not work in bash-2.0 and so on. It's not quite related to to the distribution/kernel version you use but the shell you use.

So, without details, it's not possible to assert whether a script that works on Ubuntu will work on RHEL. If you use the same shell and same version
on both machines then yes, it's going to work as expected (barring some very odd cases).

Comment: And also, it's highly dependent on the external commands the shell script invokes.